# How to display show the records of datename & year using this approach

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

This code display the record by month and year
example:

- July 2015
- August 2015
- September 2015

here's my code its working.

```
<?php
  $qry = "SELECT count(*), monthname(curdate), year(curdate) FROM cswd_records GROUP BY month(curdate), year(curdate)";
   $run = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error()); 
  ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<Center><span class="impactsoc">Total Applicants by Month</span></center><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
<th># of Applicants</th>
<th>Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>       
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)) {?>
        <tr>
        <td width="250"><h5><?php echo $row['count(*)']; ?></h5></td>
         <td width="250"><h5><a href="month.php?monthyear=<?php echo $row['monthname(curdate)'];?>-<?php echo $row['year(curdate)'];?>"><?php echo $row['monthname(curdate)'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['year(curdate)'];?></h5></a> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><center><h4><i>Total Applicants:</i><font color="red"> <?php echo $row['count(*)']; ?></font></h4></center></td>
      </tr><?php }?>

</table>
```

this is my problem. how to display all the list of july 2015
(it works if I just want to show the month or year. I dont know if its 2 value).

url value:

```
month.php?monthyear=August-2015
```

this one is working if only 1 value. How to display both month and year?

```
$myr = $_GET['monthyear']; //getting the details by link(a href)
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cswd_records WHERE monthname(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr) ."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put year also

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cswd_records WHERE
monthname(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr) ."' 
AND year(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr) ."'");
```

EDIT

```
$myr = explode("-", $_GET['monthyear']);
```

Use

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cswd_records WHERE
monthname(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr[0]) ."' 
AND year(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr[1]) ."'");
```

Comment: Surely this approach loses the benefit of using prepared statements as the parameters are included inline with the sql and not bound as parameters as they should be!

Comment: @kimdecastro, why put `AND` after `)`, put it before as I did. As RamRaider said, you should use the proper way of prepared statements. There is no benefit of use prepared statements this way.

Comment: it doesnt work. please have a check on my A HREF (link) 2 echo row monthname & year

Comment: its woking now I must get the 2 variable. ty for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cswd_records WHERE monthname(curdate) ='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr) ."' 
AND year(curdate)='". mysql_real_escape_string($myr1) ."'");
```

Thanks to @Harshit Shrivastava

Comment: Or if you are using same variable, then I have posted the solution too.